# White pages on sub domains after server transfer

Tags: multisite

I recently just moved servers with a multisite install and kept the same domain.

I can access all the backend features and logins for each subdomain but when trying to visit each subdomain site, it just loads a blank white page.

I have setup wildcard subdomains in cpanel and checked the wp options and wp config.

Has anyone else ever had this issue when migrating servers?

Comment: White blank pages normally indicate a PHP Fatal error has occurred, but the error isn't being displayed on the frontend. Can you look through your error logs and find the error message?

Comment: I have not been able to find or setup error logs yet.  I just find it strange that only the subdomains on the account are getting the white screen and the entire backend works fine.  I don't see anything wrong with the theme files either.

Comment: Ah without knowing what the error is there's not a lot that can be done to help

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/radiobra/public_html/wp-content/themes/radioresponsive/index.php on line 15

Comment: I checked the theme file and it looks fine.

Comment: Clearly it isn't, without seeing that file I can only guess at what's on line 15 and the bits around it

Comment: I never touched the theme files and they worked on the previous server.  What would change that would now give an error?

    <h1><?php echo get_option('radio_options')['blog-header'];?></h1>

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Also the other theme is saying the exact same error and the code looks fine as well.

<div id="whatstrending"><h1><?php echo get_option('radio_options')['blog-header'];?></h1></div>

Comment: Oooh, I know the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your comments state that the line in question that gives the fatal error causing your white pages is this line:

```
<div id="whatstrending"><h1><?php echo get_option('radio_options')['blog-header'];?></h1></div>
```

Most notably:

```
get_option('radio_options')['blog-header'];
```

Or more specifically:

```
functioncall()[]
```

This is invalid PHP up until recently, and your new host doesn't run a version of PHP that supports this.

You can fix it by refactoring it from:

```
echo get_option('radio_options')['blog-header'];
```

to:

```
$options = get_option('radio_options');
echo $options['blog-header'];
```

Rinse repeat in any other situation that follows the same pattern. As a sidenote, the `function()['arrayaccess']` pattern is an anti-pattern, a single line should do a single thing, and calling a function then accessing its return value is 2 things. Not to mention that it will fail if the function doesn't return an array.

Comment: Or he could update his php version via his cpanel easy Apache options.  But I also agree with your last point.